# Como converter uma string para um inteiro em um programa socket?

Tags: string, python-3.x, socket, tkinter, int

Aqui está um trecho do código:

```
def CriarServer(self):
     Host = self.Txt1.get() 
     Port = self.Txt2.get()

     sockobj = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM) #Erro

     sockobj.bind((Host, Port))
     sockobj.listen(5)

     while True:

        data = conexão.recv(1024)

        if not data: break

        conexão.close()
```

Como eu estou em um programa em Tkinter, pedi ao Python para que ele pegasse o texto de duas entradas, uma de porta e outra de host, porém quando se pega o texto de uma *Form*, ele vem como uma string e o socket *bind* só aceita números inteiros para fazer a atribuição. Como converto a string para `int`?

Erro:

> sockobj.bind(int(Host, Port))TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer.

---

Comment: Tinha vária pessoas dando negativo sem motivo algum.

Comment: Muito obrigado, quando der o tempo eu aceito a resposta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prsesumo que precises que o `Port` seja um inteiro, então faz:

```
Host = int(self.Txt1.get())
```

[int()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int)

Assim tens de ter a certeza que o input vai ser númerico, caso contrário isso vai gerar erro `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:...`

Podes certeficar-te que "há de ser inteiro" e adaptar ao teu código assim:

```
Host = None
while not isinstance(Host, int):
    try:
        Host = int(input('número'))
    except ValueError as err:
        print('numro incorreto')
```

O erro que colocaste num edição recente, já depois desta resposta que era acerca de outra questão, acontece porque estás a tentar tranformar em inteiro duas variáveis, `int(Host, Port)`, não pode ser porque no metodo bind entra como argumento um tuple `(host, port)` em que o host é uma string e o port é um inteiro, ou seja, tens de fazer só:

```
sockobj.bind((Host, Port))
```

Em que port será um inteiro, com a maneira que coloquei acima, `Host = int(self.Txt1.get())`